# Does POSIX-standard require it's specifications to be implemented in the C language only?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix

Based on the articles I've read on wikipedia and other sources, I've learnt that operating systems like the ones based on UNIX implement the POSIX-API in C. Moreover, I'm yet to find a POSIX-compliant operating system that implements the POSIX-functionalities in any language other than C.

So, does the POSIX-standard require it's specifications to be implemented in the C language only? Can someone implement the POSIX-functionalities for their own(self-made) operating systems in any other programming language like (pure)Rust and get that operating system certified as a POSIX-compliant OS?

Comment: POSIX requires the system to have C headers with certain API. If you consider those (and the bindings required to support them) as harming the purity of the implementation, then no. We can't.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for the comment. So are you saying that the performance overhead of using bindings for C headers is the only reason why people don't write APIs in any other language other than C? Am I correct?

Comment: I can't comment about the performance overhead. All I said is that you *must* have some C in there simply because the POSIX specification demands that you do. If that is unacceptable for whatever reason, POSIX compliance is impossible.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thanks for explaining it. I can think of two reasons why developers stick to C for implementing POSIX API:
1) C is one of the fastest languages for the task
2) By looking at C, experience programmers can literally make out what the assembly code will be for that particulare line/snippet

Comment: The Posix API is a C API. Posix defines how C programs invoke OS servlces. (Since it is an extension to the C standard, it also includes some interfaces which have less to do with the OS. Loke the C standard itself, Posix does not care how the API is implemented, including the language it is written in. You could use Rust to implement the library if you have away for C programs to transparently call Rust functions. But the intent is to create a way to write portable C programs. Clearly, a Rust program cannot be a portable C program. So that part of Posix simply doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely anybody will ever use header definitions other than for C/C++ again, which are necessary to [comply with the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

So while technically not necessary, it is practically a necessity or you need to simulate C header behavior from another language + c99 by ISO specification.
"The C-language Development utility c99 shall be supported." (ISO C standard)
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

It is however possible and often practical to conform to the POSIX System Interfaces(what people usual refer to as POSIX-API) and parts of "Shell and Utilities".
To that regard POSIX is "flawed", because it has a "language-lockin".